# Python - time complexity of not in set

Tags: python, performance, set, time-complexity, big-o

I know the time complexity of checking if x in set is O(1) but what about if x not in set? Would that be O(1) still because set is similar to a dictionary?

Comment: `x not in s` is the same as `not (x in s)`, so both O(1) average case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x not in some_set` just negates the result of `x in some_set`, so it has the same time complexity. This is the case for any object, set or not. You can take a look at the place where the CPython implementation does [`res = !res;`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/ceval.c#L5167) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

For more information on the time complexities of Python Data Structures please reference this https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.

From this it is shown that `x in s` performs O(1) on average and O(n) in worst case. So as pointed out by 
user2357112 `x not in s` is equivalent to `not x in s` which just negates the result of `x in s` and will have the same time complexity.